# Can't co-create object

Tags: jacob

i made a dll in .net and call that from java program using jacob.since yesterday i have windows 7 32 bit os so program run successfully.now i formated and install windows 7 64 bit os.so following error encounter:

```
com.jacob.com.ComFailException: Can't co-create object
    at com.jacob.com.Dispatch.createInstance(Native Method)
    at com.jacob.com.Dispatch.<init>(Dispatch.java)
    at com.jacob.activeX.ActiveXComponent.<init>(ActiveXComponent.java)
    at product.Control_product.main(Control_product.java:21)
```

Register all the dll files but the error is occured.

Comment: Error is solved.put the same jacob.dll and jacob.jar in the server \lib folder,jdk bin and lib folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Error is solved.put the same jacob.dll and jacob.jar in the server \lib folder,jdk bin and lib folder

Comment: do we need to register it?

Comment: I don't understand.
where do I have to put these files?

Answer (score 7):

Use a 32bit JVM to execute your code.

The DLL of the COM object you are trying to use needs to be registered.  The jacob dll's do not provided they are available in the library path.

Answer (score 0):

see here http://netheadaches.wordpress.com/2012/04/22/jacob-cant-co-create-object/

You need to register your dll file using the 64bit version of regasm.exe