# Jacob can't connect to iTunes on WIndows XP

Tags: java, windows-xp, itunes, jacob

I have a user getting this error:

```
com.jacob.com.ComFailException: Can't co-create object
    at com.jacob.com.Dispatch.createInstanceNative(Native Method)
    at com.jacob.com.Dispatch.<init>(Dispatch.java:99)
    at com.jacob.activeX.ActiveXComponent.<init>(ActiveXComponent.java:58)
    at com.jthink.jaikoz.ituneshelper.WindowsJacobUpdateItunesWithChanges.updateItunes(WindowsJacobUpdateItunesWithChanges.java:89)
    at com.jthink.jaikoz.TagSaver$UpdateITunes.run(TagSaver.java:444)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

When I try to use Jacob to talk to iTunes, I don't have such a problem. I found [this article](http://netheadaches.wordpress.com/2012/04/22/jacob-cant-co-create-object/), but I don't have the issue of using 64-bit (I'm on Windows XP which is always 32-bit). I think Windows XP may be the issue as most of my customers are on Windows 7 or 8 and don't report this problem.

Comment: Never used Jacob or any itunes integration whatsoever but checkout this link. Theres a solution to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9579976/cant-co-create-object

Comment: may be you should try putting the same dll and jar file of jacob